# How do I get these two values in asp?

Tags: file-io, vbscript, asp-classic

How I can read two values, one line in the txt file?

value1 , value2

```
set nesne = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   

Response.Write "Son 10 Kayıt<br/>"

Const nLines = 10
set AO = nesne.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("log.txt"),8)
NumberOfRecords = AO.Line - 1
AO.Close

set AO = nesne.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("log.txt"),1)
For j = 1 To NumberOfRecords - nLines
    s = AO.SkipLine
Next

'You could put the rest into an Array
'v = Split((f.readall), vbLf)

For j = 1 To nLines
    Response.Write AO.ReadLine 
    Response.Write "<br/>"
Next

AO.Close
```

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific. Are you looking to read two values from a single line of a text file, or are you looking to place two lines from a text file into different variables?

Comment: I am looking two values from a single line of a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
arrayVariable = Split(strLine,",")
```

This will take whatever is in strLine (which should be the line you just read in) and save it to an array (arrayVariable) using ',' as a delimiter.